# How do I convert lambda parameters to usable objects?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to stream a list of Doubles into a `Map<Double, Double>`, where the keys are the Doubles in the original list, and the values are some computed value.

This is what my code looks like:

```
// "values" is a List<Double> that was passed in
ImmutableMap<Double, Double> valueMap = values.parallelStream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p, p -> doThing(values, p)));

private Double doThing(List<Double>, Double p) {
    Double computedValue = 0.0;
    // Do math here with p
    return computedValue;
}
```

However, IntelliJ is complaining that `p -> p` is not a valid lambda expression - it's complaining about a cyclic inference. I'm also getting an error when I call `doThing`, because `p` is a lambda parameter and not a Double.

When I try to cast `p` to a `Double` in the call to `doThing`, that fails to cast.

Am I missing something really obvious? It seems like there's no way to actually do anything with my lambda parameters...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem here is simply that your collecting operation returns a `Map<Double, Double>` but the type of `valueMap` is `ImmutableMap<Double, Double>`.

You also forgot to give a name for the `List<Double>` parameter in `doThing` but I assume it was only a typo when writing the question.

Comment: You're right about the typo, sorry about that. Changing it to a Map instead of an ImmutableMap seems to have fixed the problem. Do you know why the errors I saw were seemingly unrelated? For an error like that, I would have expected something like a type mismatch error between the return value of .collect() and the declared type of valueMap. Why in the world would a declared type mismatch cause a cyclic inference error...?

Comment: @sichinumi I tried it with Eclipse and got _Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to ImmutableMap<Double,Double>_. So the error you got is indeed a bit weird.

Comment: Afaik, IntelliJ uses `javac` just like Netbeans, so I can confirm that error messages connected to either Generics/Type Inference or Lambda Expressions can be confusing and far away from the actual problem. Sometimes, just a forgotten `)`, `>` or `;` can cause plenty of absurd, unhelpful error messages.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the problem is that `Collectors.toMap` accumulates the element into `Map<K,U>` (the current implementation returns an `HashMap` but it's an internal detail).

If you want to collect into an [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html), you can use the [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) collector.

Use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) as the downstream collector and provide the function `map -> ImmutableMap.copyOf(map)` as a finisher.

```
ImmutableMap<Double, Double> valueMap = values.stream()
                .collect(collectingAndThen(toMap(p -> p, p -> doThing(values, p)), ImmutableMap::copyOf));
```